# Query does not return anything

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ms-access, oledbconnection

I am trying to get some results from the database, but the query is failing!

```
String sqlFindModel = "SELECT * FROM [PRODUCT] WHERE [PN] LIKE ('*" + textBox1.Text + "*')";
```

When I trim the "WHERE [PN] LIKE ..." part, it works fine.
When I replace LIKE to '=' and look for Exact value, it works.

I am confused.

PS - It is Interesting, when doing Query in ACCESS directly, you have to use *; but when using C# and connect to MS Access, need to use %... interesting!

Comment: 1) Use parameters
2) % is the LIKE operator, not *

Comment: Make sure you sanitize your input or a malicious user could end up dropping your table or executing all kinds of devious code via a sql injection attack.

Comment: @Maciej Manually sanitizing input for SQL is an exercise doomed to fail in most cases.  You're virtually always better off using a parameterized query or equivalent in which you aren't responsible for sanitizing it yourself.

Comment: You can actually use * in access itself (dao/ansi 89) its oledb that uses the ansi 92 interface so wants the %

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`*` isn't used for wildcarding in [SQL LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) statements - `%` is.

However, you *shouldn't* just change your code to use `%` - you should fix your code so it's *not* vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), instead. You should use parameterized SQL instead. See the documentation for [`OleDbCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Consider whether Access' undocumented `ALike` comparison operator would make this easier to deal with.

```
"SELECT * FROM [PRODUCT] WHERE [PN] ALike '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'"
```

`ALike` signals Access' db engine to expect ANSI wild cards (% and _ instead of * and ?).  So your query could then work the same regardless of whether you're running it from within an Access session, or from outside an Access session using OleDb.

I've seen objections to `ALike` due to the fact that it's not standard SQL.  However, when adapting Access queries for other db engines, I much prefer to change `ALike` to `Like` rather than having to change * and ? to % and _.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the * character with a %